# Fully load entity with JPA before detaching it?

Tags: java, jpa, entity, lazy-evaluation, eager

I need to do some processing on an Entity. I'd like it to be outside a transaction. The thing is this entity contains some lazy-loaded fields so that my program fails on accessing some of them because of not having a session active.

The most natural thing to do would be to fully initialize such entity once it's loaded but still in transactional scope (before detaching it). But I can't find how to do that. Is there really no simple method do such a trivial thing? I'd like to stay behind JPA spec.

For some reason fetch all properties in jpql does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call a method on the lazy proxies you want to initialize:

```
SomeEntity e = ...;
e.getFoos().size(); // now foos is initialized
e.getBar().getName(); // now bar is initialized
```

To load the whole state at once using JPQL, you need to use fetch joins:

```
select e from SomeEntity e
left join fetch e.foos
left join fetch e.bar
where ...
```

Comment: The second option would be a way to go for me (even if I had to list about a dozen highly nested properties...) except its not working for some reason - fields still are PersistentSets which aren't loaded (and accessing them results in exception - "no session"). Do it have something to do with cascade options? I did not define any on those fields.

Comment: Check the generated SQL. It should work fine, even if the spec only says that fetch is a "hint". But nothing forbids you to use fetch joins, and to make sure everything is loaded using the first technique. Anyway, it's impossible to diagnose anything without seeing a single line of code and a precise description of the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right. It's working now. The thing was I was using two queries and I edited the wrong one. I guess there is no easier method to do what I wanted to do. Thanks!